# Alphabets in a list

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I'm trying to print the alphabets using list so I used a char in the list

```
List<char> alphabets = new List<char>();
alphabets.Add(Convert.ToChar("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));
```

so I use a foreach loop to print every alpha but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work? It isn't clear what you mean by "print"? Do you mean to the console? One letter per line?

Comment: You cannot convert an entire string larger than 1 character into a single char, that's just not how a char works.  Perhaps convert the string into a char array or list?

Comment: Yes print single letter per line

Comment: I see no foreach loop in your code. You haven't provided an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just loop through a string:

```
foreach (char c in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") 
{
}
```

And if you really need a List:

```
List<char> charList = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToChar` will convert something *to a single character*. If you want to have your string split into a group of single characters, you can use the fact that it implements `IEnumerable<char>` already:

```
List<char> alphabets = new List<char>();
alphabets.AddRange("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var chars = new char[] { 'a','b','c', /*...*/ };
foreach(char c in chars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

This creates a new `System.Char[]` with the required contents.
Whilst looping through each `char`, you can print it out using `Console.WriteLine(/*...*/);` or do any additional processing for your own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
void Main()
{
    List<char> alphbets = new List<char>();

    alphbets.AddRange("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray());

    foreach (var element in alphbets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<char> alphbets = new List<char>();
alphbets.Add(Convert.ToChar("A"));
alphbets.Add(Convert.ToChar("B"));
alphbets.Add(Convert.ToChar("C"));

// and so on

foreach(char c in alphbets.Items)
{
 Console.WiteLine(c);
}
```